# recursive function with multiple parameters in javascript/reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

I am writing some react code, in which I build a list of diagnoses. These diagnoses are build dynamically, so one can add sub diagnoses and attributes to them by clicking them. Therefore, I want to know where some potential diagnosis is placed in my list, and therefore when creating a new diagnosis, I give it a path as an attribute, which I can then use to navigate to it from the list.

I want to be able to set an attribute 'showRequirements' to a given diagnosis, and for this I implement the following two functions:

```
onClick = (path) => () => {
let currentDiagnosis = this.state[path[0].type][parseInt(path[0].key, 10)];
if (path.length > 1) {
  this.showRequirementsFromPath(path, currentDiagnosis.algorithm.children, 1)
}
else {
  currentDiagnosis.showRequirements = !currentDiagnosis.showRequirements;
}
this.setState({
  [this.state[path[0].type][parseInt(path[0].key, 10)]]: currentDiagnosis,
})
```

}

```
showRequirementsFromPath = (path, diagnosis, counter) => {
if (counter < path.length) {
  diagnosis[path[counter].key].showRequirements = true;
  this.showRequirementsFromPath(path, diagnosis[path[counter].key], counter + 1);
}
else {
  diagnosis.showRequirements = !diagnosis.showRequirements;
}
```

}

The onClick works when the path has length 1, so I believe the problem is in the showRequirementsFromPath function. If I run this with a path of length > 1, the app crashes, and I get the error message 'Too much recursion'. However, if I delete the diagnosis.showRequirements = !diagnosis.showRequirements from the else in showRequirementsFromPath, the app doesn't crash, and it does everything perfectly besides setting the attribute showRequirements.

This is my first post in here, so please tell if I'm breaking some guidelines/what I can do better in future posts.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: As asked, the type of path[0].key is String. Note that path[counter].key is an integer when counter > 0.

Comment: please add the type and possible values of `path[0].key`.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I am so sorry, I just found out that the problem was elsewhere in the code. I believe the code I have posted is actually correct.